# Correct use of the AndWhere filter in AR

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I'm using the following query to get the total numbers to display a small dashboard graph above Gridview.

I would like to know the correct way for this query to work both when a manager is selected (`registration_id`) and when ALL (without the `registration_id` parameter) is selected.

**INDEX VIEW FILE**

```
$total_received_quota = Quota::find()
        ->where(['quota_status'=> 1])
        ->AndWhere(['quota_registration_id' => $manager])
        ->sum('quota_valor');
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new QuotaSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $manager = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('QuotaSearch')['quota_registration_id'];
    $manager = isset($manager) ? $manager : null;

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel'   => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider'  => $dataProvider,
        'manager'       => $manager,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: use [andFilterWhere()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#andFilterWhere()-detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This way :

```
 $query= Quota::find()->where(['quota_status'=> 1]);

    if(isset($manager) && $manager!=null)
    {
      $query->andWhere(['quota_registration_id' => $manager]);
    }

  $total_received_quota=  $query->sum('quota_valor');
```